# Issue with mat-icon module when used at inner level of folder structure

Tags: angular-material

I have imported mat icon module in the module and i am trying use mat-icon inside few component with the nested folder within. but It's giving the error.

```
Tried declaring at root level in app.module.

'mat-icon' is not a known element:   
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

<div class="upload-icon">[ERROR ->] <mat-icon aria-label="arrow upward icon">arrow_upward</mat-icon></div>
```

Comment: Post the code for your app module, and post the code for the component that contains: `<div class="upload-icon"><mat-icon ...`.